# Jest Testing Coverage - Errors When Files Don't Have Tests

Tags: jestjs

I have Jest tests in my React project, and I don't have coverage on all files yet. However, I am getting these errors:

```
Failed to collect coverage from  /home/user/Development/VideoManager/VideoManagerClient/src/components/AppContent/VideoListLayout/VideoListLayout.js
ERROR: Cannot read property 'coverageData' of null
STACK: TypeError: Cannot read property 'coverageData' of null
```

The file being mentioned here does not yet have unit tests created for it. I want it to simply be tracked as lacking coverage and thus bring my whole coverage stats down, rather than throwing an error.

In addition, when I run individual tests in my IDE, my logs get filled with even more of these errors because it's not running the other tests.

How can I fix this?

PS. Here is my Jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": 80
      }
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts",
      "!src/serviceWorker.js"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/test/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/test/setupTests.js",
      "<rootDir>/test/mock/.*",
      "<rootDir>/test/exclude/.*"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue while using `jest version 24.1.0` and `babel-jest version 23.6.0`.

Solved it by updating `babel-jest` version to `24.0.0`.